# Understanding kinda weird javascript array notation

Tags: javascript, arrays

In a script I saw this:

```
function addToPoint(x, y) {
    x = Math.floor(x/SCALE);
    y = Math.floor(y/SCALE);
    if (!points[[x,y]]) {
      points[[x,y]] = 1;
    } else if (points[[x,y]]==10) {
      return;
    } else {
      points[[x,y]]++;
    }
  drawPoint(x*SCALE,y*SCALE, points[[x,y]]);
```

}

So what's happening, I think, is this:

```
points[[x,y]] = 1;
```

Here, the guy dynamically creates a field for the points-object (which was declared empty). By passing it like this, it gets converted to a string and the x and y params of the function will make up that field.

So, in effect, if i called addToPoints(3,4) the code results in this:

```
points["3,4"] = 1;
```

This is really weird to me: is [x,y] a legit array? What kinda notation is that? What's the rule behind that??

I played around with the code a bit and it seems like you can declare an array in JavaScript just by doing this:

```
[x,y];
```

Help, tips and clarification appreciated!

Comment: What is the surprising part here for you? The use of arrays as array indices? It seems hacky, but it does work (for numbers). Could be useful for golfing, actually.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: The question is, how come that [x,y] is an array, if it is never declared like this, e.g.: var arr = [x,y]. And if it were an array, shouldnt the code be like this: poiints[arr[0],arr[1]]; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var arr = [ x, y ];` is simply how you [declare an array in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) with `x` and `y` as the first and second elements.

The second part `points[[x,y]]` is a little more confusing. Basically what happens is that  the `arr` array gets converted into a string (something like `[ 1, 2, 3 ]` will become `"1, 2, 3"`) which will then be used as the property name on the `points` object.

A little less terse (and with actual numbers instead of the `x` and `y` parameters) what happens looks somewhat like this:

```
var points = {};

var arr = [ 1, 3 ];
var key = arr.toString(); // '1, 3'

points[key] = 1; // { "1, 3": 1 }
```

Comment: Hey, well, I get that it is converted into a string. The weird thing is (it's not clear from the question) that nowhere in the code there is an array initiated like var arr = [x,y];. The [x,y] simply appears there in that function and nowhere else.

Comment: So I don't have to declare the array? putting points[[x,y]] will make [x,y] an array automatically? becasue if it were var arr = [x,y], then shouldnt it be: points[arr[0],arr[1]]; ??

Comment: No. My above example is what's happening if you'd write `points[[ 1, 3 ]]`

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you miss here is the fact that when you use something as a property name on a project it being converted to the string:

```
points[[x,y]]
```

really doing

```
points[[x,y].toString()]
```

You can try to test it with

```
points[{}]
```

it will create key `[object Object]`

Reason to use it is that there is no support for two-dimensional arrays in javascript, however you can have array of arrays

And this little trick allow to use one dimensional array as a two-dimensional.

Here is funny trick:

```
Array.prototype.toString = function ( ) { return this.join(':') }
```

Now 
    points[[x,y]] = 1

will create key `x:y` and not `x,y`